# Determine, store and print all integers within given range

Tags: c, pointers

This is what I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int betweenArray(int a, int b){
    int *arr,i,range;
    range = b - a + 1;
    arr = (int *)malloc(range*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<range;i++){
        arr[i] = a++;
    }
return * arr;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a,b,i;
    int range;

    printf("Give numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    range = b - a + 1;


    for(i=0;i<range;i++)
        printf("%d\n",betweenArray(a,b)); 
    return 0;
}
```

So when I run this and give for example 2 and 5 as arguments I get as a result: 2 2 2 2 instead of 2 3 4 5. I can't find where I made my mistake.

Comment: You return the first integer from an allocated array, always. You also have a memory leak as you allocate memory but never free it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calculating the sequence, but you only return the first number of it.

The return value of `betweenArray` is `int` instead of `int *` and you do `return * arr;` instead of `return arr;`. After fixing that, in `main`, you would need to do:

```
int *sequence = betweenArray(a,b);
for (i=0;i<range;i++)
    printf("%d", sequence[i];
```

But it would be better if the function would return the array and the number of elements in it, for example like that:

```
int *betweenArray(int a, int b, int *numElements){
    int *arr,i,range;
    range = b - a + 1;
    arr = (int *)malloc(range*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<range;i++){
        arr[i] = a++;
    }
    if (numElements) {
        *numElements = range;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a,b,i;
    int *sequence;
    int range;

    printf("Give numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);

    sequence = betweenArray(a,b,&range);

    for(i=0;i<range;i++)
        printf("%d\n",sequence[i]);

    free(sequence); // Be nice, clean up.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this seems to clear some things up. Didn't understand pointers as good as I thought.

Comment: @captain: you might look at [the very similar (but independent) solution](http://ideone.com/3oF1u) that returns a new array.

Answer (score 1):

This code suffers from multiple issues, all due to a single misunderstanding of pointers and their relation to arrays in C.

- Your `betweenArray` should be returning `int*`, not `int`
- Hence, you should not be dereferencing `arr` on the return line
- You should call `betweenArray` once and store its result, instead of calling it in a loop
- You need to call `free` on the result returned from `betweenArray`

Comment: if I understood correctly. 1)I should have int *betweenArray(int a, int b). 2) I will return arr 3) In my main function I will have something like p = betweenArray(a,b) where p is a pointer. Right? I didn't understand the last part you said though.

Comment: @captain You got the first three right (your loop will be using `p[i]` to print the next element). The last one is the simplest: once your loop is over, call `free(p)` to undo the effect of `malloc` and give the dynamically allocated memory back to the system.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling betweenArray() with the same parameters that do not change for the different runs through the for-loop - thus you'll always get the same result. You'll have to either call betweenArray() with an index, or call it once and return an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns first element of array, which is identical to 'a'. Really I'm totally confusing what you want to do here. The context you use for betweenArray() is iterator, which isn't possible in C directly.

If you want to do this using iterator, you should use three functions: 1) which creates it (likely as allocating structure and setting values), 2) getting next value from it or end-of mark, 3) deinit and deallocate.

OTOH this is much simple to do with 'for' cycle.